# Can't use gridToVtk

Tags: python, anaconda, vtk, paraview

I am trying to use the gridToVtk function in anaconda/spyder so I can export and process my results in paraview, but by using the code below:

```
from evtk.hl import gridToVTK
```

I got the error message: No module named 'evtk.hl'
Whilst this could be an installation error, the chances are relatively low to be so as I used the `conda install -c conda-forge pyevtk` command twice in the conda prompt window.
I also tried by executing the code

```
from evtk import gridToVTK
```

but the error message was given as follows: cannot import name 'gridToVTK' from 'evtk' (C:\Users\ ######\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\evtk_*init*_.py)

Whilst doing on it python maybe a viable solution, that is not possible the other modules I used for my program are installed via conda.

Answer (score 0):

you import pyevtk but use evtk. Try the followings:

```
import pyevtk
from pyevtk.hl import grirdToVTK
```

I hope it works.